# Fill the missing dates using awk

Tags: bash, awk, difference, date-difference

I have some missing dates in a file. e.g.

$cat ifile.txt

```
20060805
20060807
20060808
20060809
20060810
20060813
20060815
20060829
20060901
20060903
20060904
20060905
20070712
20070713
20070716
20070717
```

The dates are in the format YYYYMMDD. My intention is fill the missing dates in between the dates if they are missing maximum for 5 day e.g.

```
20060805
20060806   ---- This was missed
20060807
20060808
20060809
20060810
20060811  ----- This was missed
20060812  ----- This was missed
20060813
20060814  ----- This was missed
20060815  
20060829
20060830 ------ This was missed
20060831 ------ This was missed
20060901  
20060902 ------ This was missed
20060903
20060904
20060905
20070712
20070713
20070714 ----- This was missed
20070715 ----- This was missed
20070716
20070717
```

Other dates are not needed where there is a gap of more than 5 days. For example,  I don't need to fill the dates between 20060815 and 20060829, because the gap between them is more than 5 days.

I am doing it in following ways, but don't get anything.

```
#!/bin/sh
awk BEGIN'{
          a[NR]=$1
          } {
          for(i=1; i<NR; i++)
          if ((a[NR+1]-a[NR]) <= 5)
             for (j=1; j<(a[NR+1]-a[NR]); j++)
             print a[j]
          }' ifile.txt
```

Desired output:

```
20060805
20060806 
20060807
20060808
20060809
20060810
20060811 
20060812 
20060813
20060814 
20060815  
20060829
20060830 
20060831 
20060901  
20060902 
20060903
20060904
20060905
20070712
20070713
20070714 
20070715 
20070716
20070717
```

Comment: ? Just take first data and last date and regenerate them all. `I am doing it in following ways` With awk you would have to reimplement all datetime functionality. What if the leap day is missing?

Comment: @KamilCuk . Okay, many thanks. I will do in that way. Yes, it should consider the leap years also.

Comment: @Kay: There are many more missing - for instance all dates between 5th of November 2006 and 12th of July 2007. Why don't you write them in your _Desired output_? And what does _missing maximum for 5 day_ mean?

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print
  prev=mktime(substr($0,1,4)" "substr($0,5,2)" "substr($0,7,2) " 00 00 00")
  next
}
{
  found=i=diff=""
  curr_time=mktime(substr($0,1,4)" "substr($0,5,2)" "substr($0,7,2) " 00 00 00")
  diff=(curr_time-prev)/86400
  if(diff>1){
    while(++i<=diff){ print strftime("%Y%m%d", prev+86400*i) }
    found=1
  }
  prev=mktime(substr($0,1,4)" "substr($0,5,2)" "substr($0,7,2) " 00 00 00")
}
!found
'  Input_file
```

Comment: It is printing the input file only. It is not filling the missing dates. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @Kay, When I run this solution with shown samples it prints all the missing dates for me, do you want it to save into Input_file itself? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Yes. It should print everything. I need to fill the gaps.

Comment: @Kay, its printing everything for me on terminal when I run this, could you please confirm if this gives correct output to you on terminal? If yes and you want to save output into Input_file itself then append ` > temp && mv temp Input_file` in my provided solution please, lemme know how it goes then.

Comment: @Kay, it worked well for me, could you please check if your Input_file has control M characters in it by doing `cat -v Input_file`? If yes then please do let me know we need to remove them first.

Comment: Perhaps my system TIME is not working. Is there is any other solution without `mktime`?

Comment: @Kay, this has worked well for me, could you please do lemme know awk version of yours?

Comment: @Kay, IMHO it should work in that version not sure why its not working :(

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work:

```
stringtodate() {
    echo "${1:0:4}-${1:4:2}-${1:6:2} 12:00:00"
}
datetoseconds() {
    LC_ALL=C date -d "$(stringtodate "$1")" +%s
}
secondstodate() {
    LC_ALL=C date -d "@$1" +%Y%m%d
}
outputdatesbetween() {
    local start=$1
    local stop=$2
    for ((i = $1; i < $2; i += 3600*24)); do
        secondstodate "$i"
    done
}
prev=
while IFS= read -r line; do
    now=$(datetoseconds "$line")
    if [[ -n "$prev" ]] &&
        ((
            now - prev > 3600 * 24 && 
            now - prev < 3600 * 24 * 5
        ))
    then
        outputdatesbetween "$((prev + 3600 * 24))" "$now"
    fi
    echo "$line"
    prev="$now"
done < 1
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/UnlawfulDistantDominspector#main.sh)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick GNU awk script. We use GNU awk to make use of the time-functions `mktime` and `strftime`:

```
awk -v n=5 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 2 2"}
            {t=mktime($1 " " $2 " " $3 " 0 0 0",1) }
            (t-p < n*86400) { for(i=p+86400;i<t;i+=86400) print strftime("%Y%m%d",i,1) }
            {print; p=t}' file
```

Using `mktime` we convert the time into the total seconds since 1970. The function `strftime` converts it back to the desired format. Be aware that we enable the UTC-flag in both functions to ensure that we do not end up with surprises around Daylight-Saving-Time. Furthermore, since we already make use of GNU awk, we can further use the `FIELDWIDTHS` to determine the field lengths.

**note:** If your awk does not support the UTC-flag in `mktime` and `strftime`, you can run the following:

```
TZ=UTC awk -v n=5 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="4 2 2"}
                  {t=mktime($1 " " $2 " " $3 " 0 0 0") }
                  (t-p < n*86400) { for(i=p+86400;i<t;i+=86400) print strftime("%Y%m%d",i) }
                  {print; p=t}' file
```