# How to filter output lines from bash command, based on dates in start of the line?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am getting following lines as an output of some bash pipe

```
output
20200604_tsv
20200605_tsv
20200606_tsv
20200706_tsv
```

I have a date variable in YYYYMMDD format in a variable

```
filter_date="20200605"
```

I want to apply the date operation on the output lines i.e. pick lines only where line's first part (before '_') is less than equal to filter_date.

i.e. Expected output

```
20200604_tsv
20200605_tsv
```

How to achieve this filtering in bash pipe?

I have tried following (lexicographically match the string) but not able to filter and get original names.

```
BASH_CMD_THAT_OUTPUT_LINES | sort | awk '{name = ($1); print name <= "20200605*"}'

## Answer
1
0
0
0
```

Comment: 1. Read a line 2. Transform line into `YYYY-MM-DD 12:00:00` format 3. Trasform date to seconds with `date -d <the_date> +%s`. 4. Compare arithmetically.  See ex [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752730/fill-the-missing-dates-using-awk/62753268#62753268)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk has the power to convert strings to numbers very easily by stripping what is redundant. Eg. The string 123_foo is converted to 123 if you add 0 to it. So the following operation would do what you request:

```
command | awk '($0+0 < 20200605)'
```

This method works excellently if you have a sortable date-format like YYYYMMDD. If you have a different format such as YYYYDDMM, you have to use different techniques by first converting the format. Eg.

```
command | awk '{d=substr($0,1,4)substr($0,7,2)substr($0,5,2)}(d+0 < 20200605)'
```

Remark that in the last solution, you have to invert your months and days in the last number: i.e. 20200605 is YYYYMMDD and not YYYYDDMM

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v filter_date="20200605" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="_"
  filter=mktime(substr(filter_date,1,4)" "substr(filter_date,5,2)" "substr(filter_date,7,2) " 00 00 00")}
{
  curr_dat=mktime(substr($1,1,4)" "substr($1,5,2)" "substr($1,7,2) " 00 00 00")
}
filter<curr_dat{ exit }
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v filter_date="20200605" '            ##Starting awk program from here and creating awk variable filter_date which is date set by OP till where we need to get the lines.
BEGIN{                                     ##Starting BEGIN section for this program from here.
  FS=OFS="_"                               ##Setting field separator and output field separator as _ here.
  filter=mktime(substr(filter_date,1,4)" "substr(filter_date,5,2)" "substr(filter_date,7,2) " 00 00 00")}    ##Creating filter variable which is mktime function having sub string function in it to get value inn cpoh time for current line.
{
  curr_dat=mktime(substr($1,1,4)" "substr($1,5,2)" "substr($1,7,2) " 00 00 00")     ##Creating curr_dat variable which has mktime function in it which has sub string of current line to get its epoch time for current line.
}
filter<curr_dat{ exit }                    ##Checking condition if filter date is lesser than current date then exit from program.
1                                          ##1 will print current line which will happen when current date is either lesser than or equal to current date.
' Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks RaviderSingh13 for your time and effort

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple way to match lexicographically.
following is test data and answer simulation

```
## 1. Test data
cat > /tmp/tmp_test_data <<EOF
20200605_tsv
20200607_tsv
20200604_tsv
20200718_tsv
20200606_tsv
EOF

## 2. Threshold date
check_date="20200605"

## 3. Sort, Filter and output
cat /tmp/tmp_test_data \
        | sort \
        | awk -v check_d=${check_date} '{
            name = ($1); \
            dt = (substr(name, 0, 8)); \
            if (dt <= check_d) \
            {print name}\
          }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash only:

```
while read line
do 
  [[ $line =~ ^[0-9]{8} ]] && [ ${line::8} -le 20200605 ] && echo $line
done < file  # actually command | while ...
```

Comment: Thanks James for your time and effort